# Next.js fetch failed, Error: certificate has expired

Tags: javascript, image, next.js, certificate

I'm running Next.js 14.

All of a sudden, some images stopped loading on my local. The images are still loading on my preview and production branch on Vercel.

I started getting this in my console:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12442:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async imageOptimizer (C:\git\project_name\node_modules\next\dist\server\image-optimizer.js:560:29)
    at async cacheEntry.imageResponseCache.get.incrementalCache (C:\git\project_name\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:181:65)
    at async C:\git\project_name\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache\index.js:90:36
    at async C:\git\project_name\node_modules\next\dist\lib\batcher.js:41:32 {
  cause: Error: certificate has expired
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)
      at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED'
  }
}
```

I wish I had more information to give, but I'm not really sure what to look for. I tried looking on ChatGPT and other places and they say to renew my certificate but I don't think I ever set up a certificate to begin with. I've also tried Next.js `experimental-https` but I still get the error and I've also tried this (Next.js does it for you with the experimental-https)

```
mkcert -install
mkcert localhost
```

But I'm still getting a certificate error. I've tried deleting my `.next` folder and rebuilding it but I'm still running into this issue.

Any things else I can try to do?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the issue, turns out some of the images had `www` in front of them and my Vercel did not have the `www.project_name.com` set up

Once I added that domain to my project and added the TXT file to my cloudflare, it was all good after a few minutes